# Why is my image not centered in my div in IE6 only

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-6, center

This is driving me mad !!! On my website http://www.funkychristmasjumpers.com I can't seem to horizontally centre the Funky Christmas Jumpers logo in the header in IE6. All other browsers I've tested work fine. Any CSS or HTML guru's out there who can point me in the right direction ? Here's the screenshot from IE NetRenderer
[image]

Comment: Why is this down voted? I think it's very specific and the quick, correct answer shows that enough information was given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try putting this styling on your Funky Logo div, instead of what you currently have:

```
#FunkyLogo
{
    width: 210px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove:

```
#Header {
  text-align: center;
}
```

The style seems useless, because it only contains another div, with a width of 100%, that itself has got `text-align: center` too, to center the logo.

Not sure (haven't got IE6 at hand), but I think this may cause that inner div to be shifted to the center of the #Header div, causing the logo to shift to the side.